# How would you discredit this faulty argument?

Tags: debate

Let's say I'm trying to argue that a certain activity is inherently dangerous and to be avoided at all costs, even though it is only dangerous if it is done without care, for example, driving a car.*

I could, for example, say:
"If car driving is safe, then why do car drivers get into horrible car accidents and get mangled and die horribly?"

Obviously, this argument isn't sound, because if we were to accept that this argument is sound, we would have to agree with the premise that getting into car accidents is an inevitable part of driving a car (which is false!)

This argument is also phrased in such a way it erases the people who drive cars safely by exclusively mentioning out the things that can go wrong in the process as if they are a necessary part of the process.

So, people of StackExchange, how would you tackle arguing against this faulty argument?

*Just so everyone knows, I do not actually believe in the quoted argument, it is merely to test how more experienced debaters would tackle a rhetorical question like this.

Comment: It's called the fallacy of limited choices or false dilemma. There exists the possibility to drive without injury.. much as i hate to say it.. the best course is to gather  statistics and cimpare it to other activities such as skiing, or watching television. In this way you can put a figure on how safe it is to drive a car. In the UK.. its actually far safer than the publuc believe.

Comment: This "argument" is clearly of a rhetorical variety. Are you asking for analysis of logical errors in it, or just an effective rhetorical tactic to rebut (as "discredit" also suggests), which are two very different things. One could simply mimic the argument to a point of ridiculousness:"Yes, great point, let me build on it. If eating is safe how come people choke on their food? And if walking is safe how come people fall and break their necks?", etc. Then one can transition the discussion into the more substantive area of statistics of accidents and safety margins.

Answer (score 1):

"car drivers get into horrible car accidents and get mangled and die horribly" is a valid counterargument to the claim that driving a car is completely safe. So if the other person has, indeed, made this claim, then this is not, in fact, a faulty argument. If the other person has made a clearly different claim, such as "Dying in a car accident is unlikely", then the argument is attacking a straw man. If the other person has made an imprecise claim such as "Driving a car is safe", then this argument is taking advantage of ambiguity and it's not engaging in good faith, as it is taking the most ridiculous interpretation and arguing against that, rather than trying to understand what the other person is trying to say. It's a form of equivocation: sing different meanings of "safe" as convenient.

So if this argument is taking place within a discussion, it's not possible to evaluate it separately, apart from the rest of the discussion.

If you're discussing not merely the claim that "car drivers get into horrible car accidents and get mangled and die horribly", but the use of it to support the thesis that cars should be avoided at all costs, then it's a false dichotomy, with "cars are perfectly safe" and "cars should be avoided at all costs" being the only options allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I would basically argue the same parts you did. I would say: crashes are not an inevitable part of car driving, and good drivers *don't* get into crashes. So if you are a good driver, you won't get into a crash, and you'll just be doing a favor to yourself getting around faster than other means of transportation.

Comment: If you couldn't really find the words :D

Comment: Unreasonable arguments: what all reasonable people have to argue against.

Comment: If someone runs a stop sign and plows into the good driver, then he will be involved in a crash.

Comment: But that is rare. Tell them that to succeed, you must take risks

Comment: @MathBob That should be your answer, then. The statement in your current answer is false, crashes actually _are_ an inevitable part of car driving.

Comment: No; many people never get into crashes

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, "If car driving is safe, then why do car drivers get into horrible car accidents and get mangled and die horribly?" is not an argument, for it does not make a claim, nor does it attempt to prove that claim; it merely asks a question.

Please see https://www.iep.utm.edu/argument/ for the definition of an argument.

Secondly, if your argument was "Driving [a car] is unsafe because some drivers get into accidents, dying horribly" then that is unfounded, because if driving was intrinsically unsafe, there would be no such thing as not getting into a crash. However, if driving is intrinsically safe, there would be no such thing as getting into a crash.

The solution lies here: driving is a compound of many actions, some of which, if done, are unsafe, and others perfectly safe. Moreover, the timing of these actions also determines the safety of the overall compound -- driving.

Driving is not intrinsically unsafe, nor is it intrinsically safe. Driving finds its safety in the circumstances surrounding the timing of the actions that constitute it.

Deo Gratias et Ave Maria!

Comment: I am not sure I understood the last line here as part of the answer. I am not opposing it, just unable to make sense of it in the context of the answer. Regardless, welcome to Philosophy!

Comment: @Frank Hubeny Thanks! That's just my signature/motto.